# Swift 3.0: Value of type 'IndexSet' has no member 'enumerateIndexesUsingBlock'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

Receiving `Value of type 'IndexSet' has no member 'enumerateIndexesUsingBlock'` error at enumerateIndexesUsingBlock.

```
/**
Extension for creating index paths from an index set
*/
extension IndexSet {
    /**
    - parameter section: The section for the created NSIndexPaths
    - return: An array with NSIndexPaths
    */
    func bs_indexPathsForSection(_ section: Int) -> [IndexPath] {
        var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = []

        self.enumerateIndexesUsingBlock { (index:Int, _) in
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(item: index, section: section));
        }

        return indexPaths
    }
}
```

Comment: What if use for-in instead of block?
>>> for (index,value) in self.enumerated()
{
    print("index = \(index), value = \(value)")
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Foundation type `NSIndexSet` has a `enumerateIndexesUsingBlock`
method. The corresponding overlay type `IndexSet` from Swift 3 is a collection, therefore you can just *map* each
index to an `IndexPath`:

```
extension IndexSet {
    func bs_indexPathsForSection(_ section: Int) -> [IndexPath] {
        return self.map { IndexPath(item: $0, section: section) }
    }
}
```