# Swift: Convert IndexSet to [IndexPath]

Tags: swift, indexpath

I want to get [IndexPath] from IndexSet in Swift 5.
There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217639/objective-c-how-to-convert-nsindexset-to-nsindexpath) to convert NSIndexSet to Array`<NSIndexPath *>` in Objective-C.
But there is no method **enumerateIndexesUsingBlock** in Swift 5.
Who knows the way?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/39639273/1187415 ?

Comment: Can I get full IndexPath array from IndexSet?

Answer (score 3):

Use `map` on indexes to create custom `IndexPath` like this:

```
let customIndexPaths = indexes.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
// Or, You can use the short-form, credits: @Vadian
let customIndexPaths: [IndexPath] = indexes.map { [$0, 0] }
```

There is also an initializer for `IndexPath` that you can use:

```
let indexes: IndexSet = [0, 1]
let indexPath = IndexPath(indexes: indexes) // Note: this initializer returns just one indexPath not an array `[IndexPath]`
```

Comment: The first form creates **one** indexPath, not an array.

Comment: Your last option `indexes.map { [$0, 0] }` doesn't make any sense. It results in a 2d array of integers. Btw you can simply use `indexes.map(IndexPath.init)`

Comment: @LeoDabus I forgot to mention that you have to annotate the type in this case: `let customIndexPaths : [IndexPath] = indexes.map { [$0, 0] }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension.

```
extension IndexSet {
    func indexPaths(_ section: Int) -> [IndexPath] {
        return self.map{IndexPath(item: $0, section: section)}
    }
}
```